# Вывод результата работы функции

Tags: python, функции, декоратор

Новичок в изучении Питона, написал простенький декоратор для сравнения времени заполнения функции набором цифр от 0 до N для листа и кортежа, работает он вроде корректно, однако сама функция теперь вместо ожидаемого результата в виде списка чисел - [0,1,2,N] выдает - <function generator at 0x7fe79c0f1550>. Без запущенного декоратора функция выдавала ожидаемый ответ.
Подскажите как вывести в консоль список полученных цифр?

```
from _datetime import datetime

def timeit(func):
    def mya(*args,**kwargs):
        start = datetime.now()
        result = func
        itogo = datetime.now() - start
        print(f'Функция завершилась за {itogo} сек')
        return result
    return mya


@timeit
def generator(n, type = ""):
    if type == "None":
        a = []
        for i in range(n+1):
            a.append(i)
        return a
    elif type == "t":
        a = []
        for i in range(n+1):
            a.append(i)
            b = tuple(a)
        return b


print(generator(4, "t"))
print(generator(4,'None'))
```

Comment: Вы функцию внутри декоратора не вызываете. Замените `result = func` на `result = func(*args, **kwargs)`